# Seagulls are the most carefree of all the birds

Tags: articles

> Seagulls are the most carefree of all **the** birds.

Is THE mandatory? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not mandatory. You can just as well say

> Seagulls are the most carefree of all birds.

Or even

> Seagulls are the most carefree of all.

With just about the same meaning. In the second example you would normally include this sentence in a discussion that had already mentioned birds that you were propposing were carefree.

Comment: Does this explanation hold water? "'the birds' are a specific group that is different from 'the animals', 'the insects', the humans' etc."

Comment: @user1425 Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Birds are a class of animals, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird. Another version of all the sentences could be "Of all the birds, the seagulls are the most carefree."

Comment: That is not my comment, but of one native's.